# NSURLConnection when posting

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using a `NSURLConnection` **POST** to connect to a streaming server using https.  It looks like data flows through but always seems to happen after exactly 6 minutes.  I have another implementation on Windows that receives data from the server immediately so I know it is not the server.  Is there some setting that is preventing the data and the response from coming back sooner?  My hunch is that it is some sort of timeout that is getting triggered.  I have run this test many times and it is always right around 6 minutes.

```
2013-07-04 21:35:45.072[65315:207] connection: willSendRequest:  redirectResponse: (null)
2013-07-04 21:35:45.075[65315:207] connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage: 
2013-07-04 21:35:45.239[65315:207] connection: canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: <NSURLProtectionSpace: 0x5b7ca20>
2013-07-04 21:35:45.291[65315:207] connection: didSendBodyData: 505 totalBytesWritten: 505 totalBytesExpectedToWrite: 505
2013-07-04 21:41:46.306[65315:207] connection: didReceiveResponse: 200, no error
2013-07-04 21:41:46.307[65315:207] connection: didReceiveData: 514 bytes
```

Comment: I think this could be some issue with server.

Comment: There could be a header not set in iOS but it is set in your Windows client.. are you sending any explicit headers? Are the headers the same in both requests?

Comment: Use a proxy to debug and check exactly what is sent and received and when it happens, compare the results for mobile and desktop.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "streaming server"? How exactly do you and the server utilize the HTTP protocol (chunked transfer encoding, range headers)? Do you set your body via `setHTTPBodyStream` or via `setHTTPBody`? Do you set a Content-Length header? You may show us your code.

Comment: thanks for response, the server is not mine, it is an online brokerage it works with a windows client that I developed independent of this.  that rules out server problem.  I think it is getting caught up in authentication, the 6 minute timeout is quite strange.  Does anyone know where this 6 minutes is coming from?  I also should mention that I am running on iPhone simulator.  I've updated the delegate with the following no help:     [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];

Comment: Hi by streaming server I mean a HTTPS connection initiation with a POSt that keeps sending data indefinitely.